# Cron job is not working if i use controller path

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

This is the way i m using  from set this link to my server but they not execute properly with my schedule time/cronjob one more think there is no coding issue.....

```
env php -q/http://www.oriify.com/index.php/cronjob/index
```

can you please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a wget instead of PHP. You are using a web address and PHP doesn't work that way. WGET performs a HTTP query which also allows for your environment vars.

```
wget "http://www.oriify.com/index.php/cronjob/index" -O /dev/null
```

I'm sure some might argue it's not proper and that running it locally is best, but locally doesn't allow for .htaccess and such.

Comment: Thank-you for sharing me your experience and finally i got my answer

Comment: i got my answer but i will wait for other ans too

Comment: Corrected the url, forgot the "s

Answer (score 1):

I did not get why you are running "env php" and not "php". Except from that, from what I see here you are trying to run an url using php and this is not normal.

just try to run the lines you have in your crontab first and see if they work. It think that a good place to start would be to replace the url to a script with the path to it and to replace that slash and replace it with a space (if what you want to do is to run a script in quiet mode)

Comment: I am not sure what you want to do.. but if you just want to visit that url there are other unix programs to use; if you want to run a php script (like I suppose) you need to provide a path.. something like "php -q /home/www/html/your_script.php"

Comment: just be sure that you can do what you need from the command line and after that just add that in your crontab..

Comment: since you tagged your question as "codeigniter" you could also do a google search for "codigniter cronjob" and you will find this official documentation http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Category:Advanced::CronScript

Comment: Thank for sharing me your experience but i will wait for other ans

Comment: i already run this query something like "php -q /home/www/html/your_script.php" and worked but this is my question how to run this link http://www.oriify.com/index.php/cronjob/index

Comment: just to visit an url you don't need to use php.. there are other options just to open an http connection.. like wget.. or if you really want php run as cron a file that uses file_get_contents on that url (if you have url fopen enabled)

Comment: Thanx for reply me and i got my answer (wget)